# Why does my android app crash while running this service?

Tags: android, xml

**I am trying to develop an app for the conditional call divert when batter goes to certain level for those network providers who do not support conditional call divert. I am just a starter . Please help me. Is it because we cannot make a call on the service or something else please check the error message and suggest carefully. It would be great help for me. my service goes like this**

```
package com.cospirit.nonprogress;
    import android.Manifest;
    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.BatteryManager;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;

    public class MyService extends Service {


        IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        Intent batteryStatus = getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
        boolean charginginfo = false;
        SharedPreferences spdf1 = getSharedPreferences("divertInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String numberDivert;
        int batterylevel = Integer.parseInt(spdf1.getString("battery_Level", ""));
        boolean divert ;


    public MyService()
    {}
        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

            Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
                    int chargingStatus = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
                    charginginfo = chargingStatus == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING || status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;
                    divert = false;
                    synchronized (this) {
                        while (status > 30 || charginginfo == true) {
                            if (divert == true) {
                                cancelDivert();
                                divert = false;
                                status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
                            }


                        }
                        while (batterylevel < status && status < 30 && charginginfo == false) {
                            if (divert == true) {
                                cancelDivert();
                                divert = false;
                                status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
                            }


                        }
                        while ((status < batterylevel || status == batterylevel) && charginginfo == false) {
                            if (divert == false) {
                                divertCalls();
                                divert = true;
                                status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }



            };
            Thread tr = new Thread(r);
            tr.start();
            return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
        }




        public void divertCalls() {
            try {


                spdf1 = getSharedPreferences("divertInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                numberDivert = spdf1.getString("phone_details", "");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("**21*" + numberDivert + "#"));
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
                startActivity(intent);


            }
            catch(Exception ep)
            {
                ep.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public void cancelDivert() {
            try {
                Intent intents = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intents.setData(Uri.parse("#21#"));
                intents.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intents.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    return;
                }
                startActivity(intents);
            }
            catch(Exception ep)
            {
                ep.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
       return null;
        }
    }
```

xml manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.cospirit.nonprogress">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

error msg

```
12-13 01:08:23.222 12033-12033/com.cospirit.nonprogress E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.cospirit.nonprogress, PID: 12033
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.cospirit.nonprogress.MyService: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2862)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1427)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
                                                                              at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:107)
                                                                              at com.cospirit.nonprogress.MyService.<init>(MyService.java:19)
                                                                              at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2859)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1427) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: What does the logcat error message say?

Comment: edited please help

Comment: `onBind(Intent intent)` returns null... that's certainly going to be a problem. It's the `IBinder` interface that allows an application to talk to the service...

Comment: [See here for a service example.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) Notice that they don't return null in `onBind()`

Comment: what is the solution then ?? please help me!! For your kind information i am just a starter.

Comment: you are trying to use service before creating it. don't use `getApplicationContext` in the variables secton. You can use it only in service methods after `onCreate` called. Read some `Service` basics to avoid such problems in future

Comment: i put that piece of code in service method ie onStartCommand but the errors still remain . Please help –

Comment: ANd i did return the instance of the binder at onBind method
 public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        MyService getService() {
            return MyService.this;
        }
    }

private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
 public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;

    }

Answer (score 0):

Move `getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(null, ifilter);` to your `onStartCommand`

Also Service is a Context. Simple use `this.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);`

Comment: i put that piece of code in service method ie onStartCommand but the errors still remain . Please help